# How to delete pads in etherpad-lite

Tags: etherpad

Is it possible? How? I only can create or edit created. I am using my own server.
I would like to admin or at least delete some pads.

Comment: In `/admin/plugins` you find the plugins adminpads2 and adminpads3 that provide deletion capabilities.

Answer (score 14):

if you are still expecting an answer: via the provided api.
you need the api key (e.g. /var/etherpad-lite/APIKEY.txt) and the id of the pad you want to delete (e.g. mypad).
then you send a simple http request to

http://yourserver.org:9001/api/1/deletePad?apikey=yourkey&padID=mypad

Comment: {"code":1,"message":"padID is not a string","data":null}

Comment: this post is older than four years. maybe they changed something :) 
otherwise check the parameters you provided ;)

Comment: Make sure to check the spelling of `padID`. I ran into the same issue earlier and realised that I was using `padId`.

Answer (score 0):

or if you want to have an open source solution: https://github.com/Visono/padlister
hope, that it works, it is my first open source project ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `ep_adminpads` plugin can be used to list and delete pads - it is installed by npm: see at [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ep_adminpads) or [github](https://github.com/spcsser/ep_adminpads) or even from the `/admin` route inside the `etherpad` installation.

Comment: I've one very large pad that let's etherpad crash if deleted via adminpads